# Flex: Add TOTAL column for AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, advanceddatagrid, calculated-columns

I have an AdvancedDataGrid that has a couple AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup's I would like each group to have an extra column, that shows the total of all the other columns in the group. I also need to use my own calc function to calculate the totals. Is there anyway to do this? I hope I explained this well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_10.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example here http://flexingflashing.blogspot.com/